# Difference between "À noite" and "De noite"

Tags: gramática

I am trying to figure out if there is any difference between the use of  "À noite" and "De noite" in terms of meaning or grammatically.
I found a post concerning  the difference on Ciberduvidas but am having a little difficulty generalising it, or if it even can be generalised.

> Q- 'É correto dizer: "Todo dia à noite eu saio de casa"?  Minha dúvida é em relação a "todo dia de noite".'
>
> A: 'Tanto poderá usar a expressão “à noite”, como “de noite”, dependendo
> do que quer dizer.
>
> Se pretende informar que sai de casa todos os dias no período da
> noite, que é habitual à noite sair de casa, deverá usar a locução
> adverbial “à noite”, que especifica o momento do dia, em relação a
> “todos os dias”, e deverá ficar-lhe adjacente: “Todos os dias à noite,
> eu saio de casa.”
>
> Se pretende dizer que, quando sai de casa, já é noite, então deverá
> usar a expressão “de noite”, que se liga ao acto de sair, e não aos
> dias: “Todos os dias, eu saio de casa (já) de noite.”'

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-noitede-noite/8230#

Answer (score 2):

He travels **by night**. Ele viaja **à noite**. *By* is better to explain it. He likes to go out at night. Ele gosta de sair de noite. [after it is night out.]

He is a vampire: He likes to go out by night, not by day: **Ele gosta de sair à** **noite não durante o dia**. Mas hoje ele não vai **sair de noite** (after nightfall). **But today, he won't go out at night**. Vai ficar no caixão. [had to put him in a coffin. haha]  –

by night = à noite, in most cases. de noite = at night. So, Rio by night is O Rio à noite. Paris by night. Paris à noite. Rio at night: Rio de noite.

That's about it.

But bear in mind, when the meaning in Portuguese is by night, we still might say in English at night. So that's the tricky bit.